# sort hash by one value not other

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

Brand new to Ruby. Am trying to sort a de-duplicated list of email FROM (senders) with the # of emails sent. This code is working but it's sorting alphabetically. I can't figure out how to sort it so that most # of emails is on top, etc.

```
results = []
mail_count = imap.search(["SINCE", @this_week.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  @from_array = envelope.from[0].name.to_a
  results << @from_array
end

# make the hash default to 0 so that += will work correctly
from_count = Hash.new(0)

# iterate over the array, counting duplicate entries
results.each do |v|
  from_count[v] += 1
end

from_count.sort_by do |k, v| v 
      puts "#{v} -- #{k}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from_count.sort_by{|k,v| v }
```

Should do the trick.

You can then iterate over the sorted hash and print the results.

So then your code would look like this:

```
from_count.sort_by{|k,v| v }.first(10).each{|k,v| puts "#{v} -- #{k}" }
```

The `sort_by` sorts it, then when the sorting is done we print the results.

Comment: When I do that and attempt to add "puts "#{v} -- #{k}" I get an error undefined local variable or method `v'

Comment: Don't add the puts statement. `puts` returns `nil` and screws up the sorting.

Comment: I guess i'm in over my head -- can't figure out how to print the sorted Hash in that format where it says 10 -- FROMa, 9 -- FROMb, etc. It used to print it fine, just sorted alphabetically instead of by number.

Comment: Thank you! You blew my mind just now. Last question, if you don't mind. How to only display first 10 from the ultimate puts?

Comment: Use `first(10)`. I edited again. See the [Array](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array) and [Enumerable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable) docs for many amazing methods.

Comment: Gracias! Will check those out.